# menu icon transition wont work in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

I found this animation on codepen.
But for any reason this won't work in Firefox

You can see the Animation here:
http://codepen.io/awesomephant/pen/zxBKBe

css:

```
rect {
  fill: red;
  transition: 300ms;
  transform-origin: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

svg {
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

 .toast {
 }

.boom {
  rect {
    fill: black;
  }

  .cheese {
    transform: translateY(25px) rotate(45deg);
  }

  .toast {
    transform: translateY(-25px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `-moz-` vendor prefix to `css` `transition` property http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbBJYW

Comment: i tried this, but it seems that only for firefox the values of translateY are not correct, its pretty weird

Comment: See updated codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbBJYW ?

Comment: Hi @Dennis just opened your url( http://codepen.io/awesomephant/pen/zxBKBe) with mozila firefox and it works fine even i changed the transition : 300ms to transition : 5000ms it also worked dude..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this should work in both Chrome and Firefox:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpBjPJ

```
div {
 padding: 10%;
}

rect {
 fill: red;
 transition: 300ms;
 border-radius: 3px;
}

svg {
 overflow: visible;
 width: 100px;
 height: 50px;
}

.toast {
}

.boom {
  rect {
   fill: black;
  }

  .cheese {
   transform: rotate(45deg);
  }

  .toast {
   transform: translateX(-40px) translateY(35px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
```

I think that the problem lies in the fact that Firefox does not support transform-origin for SVG.